# Wildcard www to non www redirection nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to redirect all traffic from

`www.*.*.<gTLD>`
to 
`*.*.<gTLD>`

If possible, I'd like to do that outside the block that serves the application. This block does not use a `server_name` because it listens to 5,000+ hostnames on the same app.

Do you have an idea on how to achieve that please ? All the example I find is only for named hosts....

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `server` block with a regular expression `server_name`. For example:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

Comment: nice, it's a good start. But the problem is with what you gave me www.example.com will redirect to example.com. And I don't want that. I only want subdomains to be redirected to non www.

Comment: Change the regular expression to match your specific requirement. Or if `www.example.com` is the only exception - add it to the `server_name` of your `default_server` block.

Comment: Complete regex is `server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+\..+\..+)$;`

Comment: Any idea why it does not work for me? For example this: `server_name www.example.com;    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;`
but the one you posted above does not.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Richard Smith
I came with a result of :

```
server {
    server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+\..+\..+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain;
}
```

It works well :-)

Comment: You should upvote and accept his answer then. You can add your regex (which is the only thing you modified from his answer) as a comment or an edit.